# Can you measure the height of a view on an activity that's not been loaded yet?

Tags: android, animation, button, android-activity, view

I want to make an animation on click that a button slides down to the position of another button and at the same time I'm loading another activity. This other button is on the new activity. Picture it as if a button from one activity is replacing a button on another activity, so it has to slide down to where the new button is.

Can I measure this new button's position before the activity is loaded? So I can get the animation right for all screen sizes.

Comment: This will be much, much easier if you use fragments. Activities aren't designed for complex animations.

Answer (score 1):

Activities are designed to be used as full-screen components, meaning that you understand that the other activity that pops in is going to take the full screen. If that is your goal, you can use shared element transitions with the activities to get the desired effect: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#start-transition

On the other hand, if you need both activities to stay on the screen, than you should rather to use fragments, as activities are not suited for that. For more info on that approach, see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Comment: Solved it with the first approach. Thank you! :D